# how to delete the downloaded file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a mdb file,and zipping that file using asp.net and after that I am downloading the zip file.

After downloading file I just want to delete the file from the directory by using c#?

I just tried but the downloading is done after the button click exist but I want to download the file and after downloading it is deleted from the directory.

Comment: Can you please show some code ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a example:

```
protected virtual void DownloadNDelete(string sFilePath, string sContentType)    
{   

string FileName = Path.GetFileName(sFilePath);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + FileName);
Response.ContentType = sContentType;
Response.WriteFile(sFilePath);
Response.Flush();
this.DeleteFile(sFilePath);
Response.End();

}
```

Comment: Is there any reference needed to get method DeleteFile.

Comment: It needs `mscorlib.dll`according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx and you have to download that file :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
String filename=Directory.GetFile(@"c:\filename");
File.Delete(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this code?

```
string filename = "yourfilename";
if (filename != "")
{
    string path = Server.MapPath(filename);
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
         Response.Clear();
         //Content-Disposition will tell the browser how to treat the file.(e.g. in case of jpg file, Either to display the file in browser or download it)
         //Here the attachement is important. which is telling the browser to output as an attachment and the name that is to be displayed on the download dialog
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        //Telling length of the content..
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

        //Type of the file, whether it is exe, pdf, jpeg etc etc
         Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        //Writing the content of the file in response to send back to client..
         Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
         Response.End();

       // Delete the file... 
         System.IO.File.Delete(file.FullName);    

    }
    else
    {
         Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: After button click the file will download and where I Put this code?

Comment: This code is for the delete file only. You said your file is properly being downloaded. So after the download code, write this code. Change the filename as according to your filename.

Comment: I updated my code to download and delete. Try this code.

Comment: For more information on how the download code is working see my answer on another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823065/cannot-download-exe-files-through-c-net/21823206#21823206